# Orion Context Broker (0.17.0) subscriptions information

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there any queryContext requests to get Context subscription information of an entity? Or is it still on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Orion roadmap includes an operation to get all subscriptions and other to get the details of a given subscription (by subscritpion ID). It think it is not exactly what you mean (if I understand correctly, you refer to an operation that given an entity returns all the subscription that refer to such entity) but you could combine the "get all subscriptions" operation with the `entity::id` filter to get the same effect.

Both operations and filter are still on roadmap. [This tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=0) shows implementation status and it is updated each time a new version is planned and released.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained myself well. I would like to know if there's a subscription to Cygnus. For example, I would like to know if the entity is subscribed to Cygnus or the duration time of the subscription.

Comment: You could use the method described in the answers to the question in order to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, while the API operations get implemented (see the other answer to this question), you can get subscriptions information directly from the Orion database as workaround. Looking to [the description of the subscriptions collection in the Orion Administration manual](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#csubs_collection) and with a basic knowledge of MongoDB query operations, for example you can get all the subscription to entity ID "foo" with the following query:

```
db.csubs.find({"entities.id": "foo"})
```